# How to use an explicit version of a github action

Tags: github-actions

I am currently trying to use the [CLA-Assistant-Lite](https://github.com/contributor-assistant/github-action) github action.

The workflow appears to have an [issue](https://github.com/contributor-assistant/github-action/issues/118) related to the use of Node.js 12.

Someone has opened a [pull request](https://github.com/contributor-assistant/github-action/pull/120) to address the issue that I would like to use.

I can not figure out how to modify my `.yml` to use the code from the pull request vs. the current release.

The `.yml` currently has the line :

```
        uses: contributor-assistant/github-action@v2.2.1
```

How can I modify it to use the pull request code instead of the v2.2.1 tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the uses line to reference the SHA from the commit you want to use instead of a version. It also accepts a branch. Simply change the part after the `@` symbol.

In your case I think you want:

```yaml
uses: contributor-assistant/github-action@4b65b2db8e3217d589ae15875814a011c1a9b69d
```

See the actions docs here about syntax for [uses](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsuses)